# How to put a maximum limit on file amount being uploaded using Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm allowing the upload of JPG files in my program. What I want to do is to set a limit of the amount of photos, let's say 15.

So I got the following in my JSP file:

```
<td  class="upload-pic"><input class="file-submit" type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50" multiple="multiple" accept=".jpg"/></td>
```

And here's a part of my controller. This works fine and I could obviously check here or make the program not to upload if there are more than 15 photos, BUT what I want to do is to send the user a message letting him know that he can't upload more than 15 photos.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "publish4" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView publish4(@Valid @ModelAttribute("fourthPublicationForm") final FourthPublicationForm form, final BindingResult errors,
                             @RequestParam("type") String type, @RequestParam("operation") String operation , @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        //return publish4();
    }
    long userid = us.findByUsername(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()).getUserId();
    Publication aux = ps.create(form.getTitle(), form.getAddress(), operation, form.getPrice(), form.getDescription(), 
            type, form.getBedrooms(), form.getBathrooms(), form.getFloorSize(), form.getParking(),userid);


    if (fileUpload != null && fileUpload.length > 0) {
        for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : fileUpload){

            System.out.println("Saving file: " + aFile.getOriginalFilename());


            UploadFile uploadFile = new UploadFile();

            uploadFile.setId((int) (Math.random()*1000000));

            uploadFile.setPublicationId(Long.toString(aux.getPublicationid())); 

            uploadFile.setData(aFile.getBytes());

            final long limit = 20 * 1024 * 1024; //10MB

            System.out.println("I'm about to save with id: " + uploadFile.getId());
            if(aFile.getSize() < limit && uploadFile.getData().length > 0) {
                if(aFile.getOriginalFilename().contains(".jpg")) {
                    fileUploadImpl.save(uploadFile); 
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Sth went wrong with file format");
                }

            }else {
                System.out.println("File is too big or it's empty");
            }


        }
    }
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/meinHaus/home");
}
```

As you see I declared this in my controller
@Valid @ModelAttribute("fourthPublicationForm") final FourthPublicationForm form

But I'm not sure how to get the amount of files from there and then show a message? Right now that class is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood the query correctly; if you want to check the number of files uploaded, then in your code, `fileUpload.length` would give you that. And then send a warning message to your jsp (view) from controller something like this

```
attributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMsg", "Not more than 15 files allowed!");
```

Check out this link https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-multi-file-upload-example/ (might not open in Chrome) he's done a similar thing but using List of MultipartFile for images instead of an array.
Also, with `RequestParam`, you can check the size with min and max limits, see this link for String https://www.javaquery.com/2018/02/passing-and-validating-requestparam-in.html. But, I don't know if it will work for an array of objects in your case.

Comment: Yeah you're right didn't think of this. What should I add to my JSP in order to show that message there? And also shouldn't I add a parameter of type attributes or something to my controller?

Comment: Ok I just solved it. Ended up returning a new mav adding a new string object. Thank you.

Comment: @Stackoverflowed Glad to hear